# why am i seeing the `TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV` in my TLS debug log

Tags: android, ssl, encryption

I read about it [*here*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5746#section-3.3) but it dosent make sense to me that i see it here.

On the Android client Im setting the:

```
sSLSocket.setEnabledCipherSuites(new String[] { "SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA"});
```

The java server debug is showing the `*** ClientHello, TLSv1` and

```
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

My setup are a dedicated Java server/Android client that will "only" always communicate. neither parties will never establish connection with anything else.

That's why i `setEnabledCipherSuites` the way i do.

Server/Client self signed certificated are in place only for testing.

Another thing is the line:

```
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
```

Whay am i seeing that?

debug log:
(removed much binary text to fit it in this body)

```
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Issuer:  CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0xb4ba1f6a7902bb97
  Valid from Thu Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2012 until Fri Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2013

***
found key for : 1
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19828292987711460063479095233990735206267474911720200680398978846239921718204800830196446367271259853243857782157464503041073715350900882399263842246256739265150626309452599118681530826485263986656970230214504531123471356734892063098742596709600403594811097754985241159919624822696690646908289328404173233975755485099400316319894619262629800753116491177190800509689339918111133269528385927418662146594964797904375015607937667194705579205469111691215024194198408322269068550434706560902100199589198763096214957779831336905118521574867338194318861017871505432271905525399396261074008234892595483193798680621671023145911
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 11 18:38:14 CEST 2012,
               To: Fri Oct 11 18:38:14 CEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  SerialNumber: [    ef1a4465 3fb9d4ed]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F5 6E DA 1E DD 85 08 31   D9 16 AC 37 23 DB 52 6A  .n.....1...7#.Rj
0010: FF B3 D4 E3                                        ....
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F5 6E DA 1E DD 85 08 31   D9 16 AC 37 23 DB 52 6A  .n.....1...7#.Rj
0010: FF B3 D4 E3                                        ....
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 7C EA BF 17 BB 9C 6E E6   DC 6E D3 5D 7E B5 48 0F  ......n..n.]..H.
0010: 5A A1 98 5F 15 A8 46 49   36 D2 1B F9 05 60 87 ED  Z.._..FI6....`..
0020: F8 59 E5 08 9F 06 22 0F   18 4A F6 E6 6C 23 39 E8  .Y...."..J..l#9.
0030: 4D 7E 37 BC 03 BE 76 75   12 D8 A2 88 94 82 D7 15  M.7...vu........
0040: 71 3C 8D 0D 69 A1 FA 88   E7 8F 3F F4 90 03 39 B4  q<..i.....?...9.
0050: 6B 8D 9F CE 2C B7 C1 D7   FC 36 BC 27 BA A2 55 5E  k...,....6.'..U^
0060: 55 8F 34 12 1C FF DA B9   70 C9 82 5D 18 58 CF AE  U.4.....p..].X..
0070: E9 F6 A0 31 DE 78 50 6A   57 BB 85 B0 E4 F0 2A 94  ...1.xPjW.....*.
0080: 93 17 60 DF ED 99 AB AB   B0 8C 8E 4E B8 D6 8F AE  ..`........N....
0090: EC 98 71 FE 82 98 2C 0A   E7 50 FF C6 78 6A 59 38  ..q...,..P..xjY8
00A0: 4B 25 B3 C6 1B 1A 61 32   1F 47 1B 98 96 15 C8 E5  K%....a2.G......
00B0: 12 3A C9 7A 38 81 3F 5C   DC FC DF 43 33 11 D1 42  .:.z8.?\...C3..B
00C0: 35 46 8C 35 C4 10 28 95   43 2B EC EC 65 7E 93 23  5F.5..(.C+..e..#
00D0: 5A F8 94 F4 5F C2 01 BE   EE E0 4E 8B BD CA 14 3C  Z..._.....N....<
00E0: 61 9B 78 96 F7 54 D3 68   F2 91 9F 43 57 AB C5 0E  a.x..T.h...CW...
00F0: D8 9E 51 85 08 62 F6 B4   BB A4 70 04 0F BA D2 C6  ..Q..b....p.....

]
***
SSL Key 1
SSL Trust 1
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
List all ******************
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
END List all ******************
Server started
  Waiting for connection from client...
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
  Accepted connection from 192.168.1.1, port 48544
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 2F                                     ..../
[Raw read]: length = 47
0000: 01 00 00 2B 03 01 50 80   4D 92 48 AF 0B D8 61 93  ...+..P.M.H...a.
0010: 3A 5B 82 59 32 7B 49 10   8E D7 4D 8A 54 79 13 F9  :[.Y2.I...M.Ty..
0020: FF F7 CB 50 C3 CE 00 00   04 00 05 00 FF 01 00     ...P...........
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 47
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1333808274 bytes = { 72, 175, 11, 216, 97, 147, 58, 91, 130, 89, 50, 123, 73, 16, 142, 215, 77, 138, 84, 121, 19, 249, 255, 247, 203, 80, 195, 206 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 47
0000: 01 00 00 2B 03 01 50 80   4D 92 48 AF 0B D8 61 93  ...+..P.M.H...a.
0010: 3A 5B 82 59 32 7B 49 10   8E D7 4D 8A 54 79 13 F9  :[.Y2.I...M.Ty..
0020: FF F7 CB 50 C3 CE 00 00   04 00 05 00 FF 01 00     ...P...........
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
matching alias: 1
%% Negotiating:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1333808261 bytes = { 70, 169, 125, 236, 121, 171, 92, 56, 45, 96, 98, 136, 44, 58, 34, 56, 104, 191, 215, 52, 174, 203, 70, 122, 8, 220, 79, 60 }
Session ID:  {80, 128, 77, 133, 70, 61, 202, 31, 62, 82, 4, 101, 72, 14, 10, 28, 91, 177, 233, 22, 222, 62, 115, 104, 78, 27, 93, 230, 21, 159, 152, 169}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
Cipher suite:  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 19828292987711460063479095233990735206267474911720200680398978846239921718204800830196446367271259853243857782157464503041073715350900882399263842246256739265150626309452599118681530826485263986656970230214504531123471356734892063098742596709600403594811097754985241159919624822696690646908289328404173233975755485099400316319894619262629800753116491177190800509689339918111133269528385927418662146594964797904375015607937667194705579205469111691215024194198408322269068550434706560902100199589198763096214957779831336905118521574867338194318861017871505432271905525399396261074008234892595483193798680621671023145911
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 11 18:38:14 CEST 2012,
               To: Fri Oct 11 18:38:14 CEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  SerialNumber: [    ef1a4465 3fb9d4ed]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F5 6E DA 1E DD 85 08 31   D9 16 AC 37 23 DB 52 6A  .n.....1...7#.Rj
0010: FF B3 D4 E3                                        ....
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: F5 6E DA 1E DD 85 08 31   D9 16 AC 37 23 DB 52 6A  .n.....1...7#.Rj
0010: FF B3 D4 E3                                        ....
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 7C EA BF 17 BB 9C 6E E6   DC 6E D3 5D 7E B5 48 0F  ......n..n.]..H.
0010: 5A A1 98 5F 15 A8 46 49   36 D2 1B F9 05 60 87 ED  Z.._..FI6....`..
0020: F8 59 E5 08 9F 06 22 0F   18 4A F6 E6 6C 23 39 E8  .Y...."..J..l#9.
00E0: 61 9B 78 96 F7 54 D3 68   F2 91 9F 43 57 AB C5 0E  a.x..T.h...CW...
00F0: D8 9E 51 85 08 62 F6 B4   BB A4 70 04 0F BA D2 C6  ..Q..b....p.....

]
***
*** CertificateRequest
Cert Types: RSA, DSS, ECDSA
Cert Authorities:
<CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE>
*** ServerHelloDone
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 1022
0000: 02 00 00 4D 03 01 50 80   4D 85 46 A9 7D EC 79 AB  ...M..P.M.F...y.
0010: 5C 38 2D 60 62 88 2C 3A   22 38 68 BF D7 34 AE CB  \8-`b.,:"8h..4..
0020: 46 7A 08 DC 4F 3C 20 50   80 4D 85 46 3D CA 1F 3E  Fz..O< P.M.F=..>
0030: 52 04 65 48 0E 0A 1C 5B   B1 E9 16 DE 3E 73 68 4E  R.eH...[....>shN
0040: 1B 5D E6 15 9F 98 A9 00   05 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01  .]..............
0050: 00 0B 00 03 59 00 03 56   00 03 53 30 82 03 4F 30  ....Y..V..S0..O0
03B0: 00 48 03 01 02 40 00 42   00 40 30 3E 31 0B 30 09  .H...@.B.@0>1.0.
03C0: 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 53   45 31 0F 30 0D 06 03 55  ..U....SE1.0...U
03D0: 04 0A 0C 06 53 50 52 49   49 44 31 1E 30 1C 06 03  ....smith1.0...
03E0: 55 04 03 0C 15 64 72 75   74 74 65 6E 2E 64 79 6E  U....smith.dyn
03F0: 64 6E 73 2D 69 70 2E 63   6F 6D 0E 00 00 00        dns-ip.com....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 1022
[Raw write]: length = 1027
0000: 16 03 01 03 FE 02 00 00   4D 03 01 50 80 4D 85 46  ........M..P.M.F
0010: A9 7D EC 79 AB 5C 38 2D   60 62 88 2C 3A 22 38 68  ...y.\8-`b.,:"8h
0020: BF D7 34 AE CB 46 7A 08   DC 4F 3C 20 50 80 4D 85  ..4..Fz..O< P.M.
0030: 46 3D CA 1F 3E 52 04 65   48 0E 0A 1C 5B B1 E9 16  F=..>R.eH...[...
0040: DE 3E 73 68 4E 1B 5D E6   15 9F 98 A9 00 05 00 00  .>shN.].........
0050: 05 FF 01 00 01 00 0B 00   03 59 00 03 56 00 03 53  .........Y..V..S
03D0: 30 0D 06 03 55 04 0A 0C   06 53 50 52 49 49 44 31  0...U....smith1
03E0: 1E 30 1C 06 03 55 04 03   0C 15 64 72 75 74 74 65  .0...U....drutte
03F0: 6E 2E 64 79 6E 64 6E 73   2D 69 70 2E 63 6F 6D 0E  n.dyndns-ip.com.
0400: 00 00 00                                           ...
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 03 5D                                     ....]
[Raw read]: length = 861
0000: 0B 00 03 59 00 03 56 00   03 53 30 82 03 4F 30 82  ...Y..V..S0..O0.
0010: 02 37 A0 03 02 01 02 02   09 00 B4 BA 1F 6A 79 02  .7...........jy.
0020: BB 97 30 0D 06 09 2A 86   48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05  ..0...*.H.......
0030: 00 30 3E 31 0B 30 09 06   03 55 04 06 13 02 53 45  .0>1.0...U....SE
0040: 31 0F 30 0D 06 03 55 04   0A 0C 06 53 50 52 49 49  1.0...U....SPRII
0050: 44 31 1E 30 1C 06 03 55   04 03 0C 15 64 72 75 74  D1.0...U....drut
0060: 74 65 6E 2E 64 79 6E 64   6E 73 2D 69 70 2E 63 6F  ten.dyndns-ip.co
0330: AD 48 3B FE 4B F9 1A 82   C9 CB 24 88 89 C3 78 8E  .H;.K.....$...x.
0340: A6 D4 FE CE 39 66 F4 48   39 16 7D 8E 08 DB 3E 24  ....9f.H9.....>$
0350: F7 FD 34 76 94 6D 37 BE   EF 53 BA 89 4D           ..4v.m7..S..M
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 861
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23496237719502336160731187123882087516857248303136016525007515477411820324389309412497616204841416737428369029539727911829957261900246123671755448783374076371585220700946079814339410006875366590448744547904237125909752424872462374722025882552253361075854663377968593894406520520763276619797341648312830067202444308703480740570155669989956271141234461583351370436392165219066579182803469381254927947452741733530570034447674553013199697877719076300791503351733152444962714618216706903270272228589537934701160017250218124068090224176369183083907456616852817429610227318879195807569316432328134191548839310114727528540673
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2012,
               To: Fri Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  SerialNumber: [    b4ba1f6a 7902bb97]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 28 E3 D4 F1 6B 59 12 54   26 6B 9B 09 6A 94 77 79  (...kY.T&k..j.wy
0010: AE BC 3D 2B                                        ..=+
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 28 E3 D4 F1 6B 59 12 54   26 6B 9B 09 6A 94 77 79  (...kY.T&k..j.wy
0010: AE BC 3D 2B                                        ..=+
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: B0 22 82 D5 1B AF 4C A7   7E D9 B4 27 F7 48 C4 D7  ."....L....'.H..
0010: DE A5 45 E6 72 D1 85 DE   CF F7 AF A4 97 7B 68 6A  ..E.r.........hj
00E0: C3 78 8E A6 D4 FE CE 39   66 F4 48 39 16 7D 8E 08  .x.....9f.H9....
00F0: DB 3E 24 F7 FD 34 76 94   6D 37 BE EF 53 BA 89 4D  .>$..4v.m7..S..M

]
***
Found trusted certificate:
[
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 23496237719502336160731187123882087516857248303136016525007515477411820324389309412497616204841416737428369029539727911829957261900246123671755448783374076371585220700946079814339410006875366590448744547904237125909752424872462374722025882552253361075854663377968593894406520520763276619797341648312830067202444308703480740570155669989956271141234461583351370436392165219066579182803469381254927947452741733530570034447674553013199697877719076300791503351733152444962714618216706903270272228589537934701160017250218124068090224176369183083907456616852817429610227318879195807569316432328134191548839310114727528540673
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2012,
               To: Fri Oct 11 18:37:21 CEST 2013]
  Issuer: CN=smith.dyndns-ip.com, O=smith, C=SE
  SerialNumber: [    b4ba1f6a 7902bb97]

Certificate Extensions: 3
[1]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 28 E3 D4 F1 6B 59 12 54   26 6B 9B 09 6A 94 77 79  (...kY.T&k..j.wy
0010: AE BC 3D 2B                                        ..=+
]
]

[2]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 28 E3 D4 F1 6B 59 12 54   26 6B 9B 09 6A 94 77 79  (...kY.T&k..j.wy
0010: AE BC 3D 2B                                        ..=+
]
]

[3]: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: B0 22 82 D5 1B AF 4C A7   7E D9 B4 27 F7 48 C4 D7  ."....L....'.H..
0010: DE A5 45 E6 72 D1 85 DE   CF F7 AF A4 97 7B 68 6A  ..E.r.........hj
00E0: C3 78 8E A6 D4 FE CE 39   66 F4 48 39 16 7D 8E 08  .x.....9f.H9....
00F0: DB 3E 24 F7 FD 34 76 94   6D 37 BE EF 53 BA 89 4D  .>$..4v.m7..S..M

]
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 861
0000: 0B 00 03 59 00 03 56 00   03 53 30 82 03 4F 30 82  ...Y..V..S0..O0.
0010: 02 37 A0 03 02 01 02 02   09 00 B4 BA 1F 6A 79 02  .7...........jy.
0020: BB 97 30 0D 06 09 2A 86   48 86 F7 0D 01 01 05 05  ..0...*.H.......
0320: 81 6C 98 BD C1 80 21 DE   02 B9 9F 0D 0B CF 07 1B  .l....!.........
0330: AD 48 3B FE 4B F9 1A 82   C9 CB 24 88 89 C3 78 8E  .H;.K.....$...x.
0340: A6 D4 FE CE 39 66 F4 48   39 16 7D 8E 08 DB 3E 24  ....9f.H9.....>$
0350: F7 FD 34 76 94 6D 37 BE   EF 53 BA 89 4D           ..4v.m7..S..M
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 01 06                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 262
0000: 10 00 01 02 01 00 54 FD   A1 78 09 68 CF 55 61 0B  ......T..x.h.Ua.
0010: BD 1E 9A 31 1D D2 83 31   31 4D 6B 6C 30 8C E3 27  ...1...11Mkl0..'
0020: 0B ED 6E C8 CC AE 15 85   C5 71 62 54 92 51 C0 C3  ..n......qbT.Q..
00E0: 6E 5B E9 90 C7 32 A2 88   15 4E 6D 60 7D 18 4B D2  n[...2...Nm`..K.
00F0: 15 70 95 3C 96 77 1D D7   A7 02 1C 6F 28 86 3C BC  .p.<.w.....o(.<.
0100: 5A C6 25 CD 94 67                                  Z.%..g
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 01 EC 03 E0 A7 DE E8   07 A4 B9 FB 07 3A AA 92  .............:..
0010: 1F 30 BA 4F 52 4E 6F 71   BA F6 8D C4 89 0E 88 66  .0.ORNoq.......f
0020: 23 B8 76 31 F3 76 E4 CE   CC F8 3F 92 0C 9D 93 86  #.v1.v....?.....
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 50 80 4D 92 48 AF 0B D8   61 93 3A 5B 82 59 32 7B  P.M.H...a.:[.Y2.
0010: 49 10 8E D7 4D 8A 54 79   13 F9 FF F7 CB 50 C3 CE  I...M.Ty.....P..
Server Nonce:
0000: 50 80 4D 85 46 A9 7D EC   79 AB 5C 38 2D 60 62 88  P.M.F...y.\8-`b.
0010: 2C 3A 22 38 68 BF D7 34   AE CB 46 7A 08 DC 4F 3C  ,:"8h..4..Fz..O<
Master Secret:
0000: 37 0F F2 9F 68 14 37 8F   E1 23 BA 31 F7 50 61 59  7...h.7..#.1.PaY
0010: 21 EE 59 E2 E9 2E 59 09   5F 68 A8 ED 11 30 1B 02  !.Y...Y._h...0..
0020: 04 22 9A C3 D2 FF 21 9F   14 95 9B 0E 45 2D 8D EE  ."....!.....E-..
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: 09 B0 B0 9D 38 E6 9C 03   2A 0B C4 3F 5D 49 7C 27  ....8...*..?]I.'
0010: 0B 41 54 3A                                        .AT:
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 5B 74 7A DA 47 AE 16 A2   AA 63 EC 0A 2F AA A1 89  [tz.G....c../...
0010: 47 D9 00 46                                        G..F
Client write key:
0000: 09 B0 BD DC E3 B6 11 1A   C9 87 3F 36 08 42 78 98  ..........?6.Bx.
Server write key:
0000: C2 E0 03 E3 38 B8 0E CC   35 85 08 3C 80 9C 23 ED  ....8...5..<..#.
... no IV used for this cipher
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 262
0000: 10 00 01 02 01 00 54 FD   A1 78 09 68 CF 55 61 0B  ......T..x.h.Ua.
0010: BD 1E 9A 31 1D D2 83 31   31 4D 6B 6C 30 8C E3 27  ...1...11Mkl0..'
0020: 0B ED 6E C8 CC AE 15 85   C5 71 62 54 92 51 C0 C3  ..n......qbT.Q..
00E0: 6E 5B E9 90 C7 32 A2 88   15 4E 6D 60 7D 18 4B D2  n[...2...Nm`..K.
00F0: 15 70 95 3C 96 77 1D D7   A7 02 1C 6F 28 86 3C BC  .p.<.w.....o(.<.
0100: 5A C6 25 CD 94 67                                  Z.%..g
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 01 06                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 262
0000: 0F 00 01 02 01 00 7F 1C   EA AC 1A C3 B6 5A 3C ED  .............Z<.
0010: 52 8F 52 05 A7 74 C0 34   05 FB AA C0 E6 ED 54 57  R.R..t.4......TW
0020: 91 80 DE CF 57 6F 34 AC   84 AA 44 99 5F DF ED DE  ....Wo4...D._...
00F0: EC 1F AE 64 34 8D 39 A8   B7 38 87 50 69 89 71 C5  ...d4.9..8.Pi.q.
0100: 4A A4 D4 58 EC 0D                                  J..X..
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 262
*** CertificateVerify
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 262
0000: 0F 00 01 02 01 00 7F 1C   EA AC 1A C3 B6 5A 3C ED  .............Z<.
0010: 52 8F 52 05 A7 74 C0 34   05 FB AA C0 E6 ED 54 57  R.R..t.4......TW
00F0: EC 1F AE 64 34 8D 39 A8   B7 38 87 50 69 89 71 C5  ...d4.9..8.Pi.q.
0100: 4A A4 D4 58 EC 0D                                  J..X..
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 14 03 01 00 01                                     .....
[Raw read]: length = 1
0000: 01                                                 .
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 16 03 01 00 24                                     ....$
[Raw read]: length = 36
0000: BF FD 57 2E 70 6E 60 FD   26 51 02 29 85 F4 96 B4  ..W.pn`.&Q.)....
0010: DE B9 58 96 98 18 A3 C9   6F E3 BD E5 E3 FA 90 7D  ..X.....o.......
0020: D7 ED 3D 7D                                        ..=.
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 36
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 36
0000: 14 00 00 0C 99 C4 41 DC   E8 86 EE 10 C5 C0 72 42  ......A.......rB
0010: 71 60 19 8C 05 25 5B 9A   53 42 48 51 61 BB 56 D2  q`...%[.SBHQa.V.
0020: 41 04 4C 91                                        A.L.
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 153, 196, 65, 220, 232, 134, 238, 16, 197, 192, 114, 66 }
***
[read] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 99 C4 41 DC   E8 86 EE 10 C5 C0 72 42  ......A.......rB
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
[Raw write]: length = 6
0000: 14 03 01 00 01 01                                  ......
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 84, 147, 38, 36, 240, 107, 166, 214, 226, 13, 147, 79 }
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 54 93 26 24   F0 6B A6 D6 E2 0D 93 4F  ....T.&$.k.....O
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 36
0000: 14 00 00 0C 54 93 26 24   F0 6B A6 D6 E2 0D 93 4F  ....T.&$.k.....O
0010: 29 31 2D E0 1D 46 87 F7   2F FA D8 F8 B2 3E 9E 7A  )1-..F../....>.z
0020: A7 B7 1B F2                                        ....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 36
[Raw write]: length = 41
0000: 16 03 01 00 24 D7 C2 B4   2C 64 20 F8 97 C2 44 FE  ....$...,d ...D.
0010: 94 B9 55 15 DB FF 17 59   EB 71 2B 2B E6 85 7B A8  ..U....Y.q++....
0020: BB A0 48 DE F4 35 05 4C   B2                       ..H..5.L.
%% Cached server session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA]
printSocketInfo......
Server socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl
   Socker address = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
   Socker port = 24586
   Need client authentication = true
   Want client authentication = false
   Use client mode = false
END printSocketInfo......
  Cipher suite used for this session: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
  Server -> receiving...
[Raw read]: length = 5
0000: 17 03 01 00 66                                     ....f
[Raw read]: length = 102
0000: 85 DD 45 9C 0C 19 1A 73   26 74 DF 3A 4A 4F 9B 53  ..E....s&t.:JO.S
0010: 97 B2 D3 AB 33 92 3F 7A   12 7B 2D 1E 95 F2 6D CE  ....3.?z..-...m.
0020: D4 54 78 A3 4F 71 A0 A5   31 24 29 90 F2 57 B1 11  .Tx.Oq..1$)..W..
0030: BA 91 64 73 8F 41 65 2A   1A 2B 6A 07 0D E8 3A CC  ..ds.Ae*.+j...:.
0040: 64 36 0D 1B 36 31 3A 1C   B2 99 77 7C C5 5A 9C 7E  d6..61:...w..Z..
0050: 3D C3 D8 44 BF E2 A3 57   E0 F3 12 47 77 2A 3E D4  =..D...W...Gw*>.
0060: 15 E1 65 4C 97 B4                                  ..eL..
main, READ: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 102
Padded plaintext after DECRYPTION:  len = 102
0000: 00 50 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A   2A 2A 2A 20 54 68 69 73  .P********* This
0010: 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 69 73   20 73 65 6E 74 20 66 72   line is sent fr
0020: 6F 6D 20 41 6E 64 72 6F   69 64 20 63 6C 69 65 6E  om Android clien
0030: 74 2E 20 48 65 6C 6C 6F   20 73 73 6C 53 65 72 76  t. Hello sslServ
0040: 65 72 53 6F 63 6B 65 74   2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A  erSocket********
0050: 2A 2A F9 D1 6F B0 48 6B   53 45 E5 44 D4 39 E5 6C  **..o.HkSE.D.9.l
0060: 85 17 34 5C 29 BC                                  ..4\).
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 92
0000: 00 46 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A   2A 2A 2A 20 54 68 69 73  .F********* This
0010: 20 6C 69 6E 65 20 69 73   20 73 65 6E 74 20 66 72   line is sent fr
0020: 6F 6D 20 50 43 20 63 6C   69 65 6E 74 2E 20 48 65  om PC client. He
0030: 6C 6C 6F 20 53 53 4C 53   6F 63 6B 65 74 20 2A 2A  llo SSLSocket **
0040: 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A 2A   DD 06 45 CE 81 4F FF C4  ********..E..O..
0050: 09 46 8A 29 B4 01 A5 3D   73 C1 AE E7              .F.)...=s...
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 92
[Raw write]: length = 97
0000: 17 03 01 00 5C 00 34 29   BF 8B EB 91 EC F1 44 F0  ....\.4)......D.
0010: 9A 41 C9 19 29 40 61 48   CC D3 D7 1B 95 03 2A 61  .A..)@aH......*a
0050: CD B6 31 B5 83 FB 93 EE   97 67 70 48 20 DA CB 38  ..1......gpH ..8
0060: E2                                                 .
********* This line is sent from Android client. Hello sslServerSocket**********
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 22
0000: 01 00 0E A1 90 92 0B E8   92 1E 0B 44 4E 4D EC 84  ...........DNM..
0010: 35 DC 18 A1 DB CF                                  5.....
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 22
[Raw write]: length = 27
0000: 15 03 01 00 16 B4 7D D9   7E 7C DA 44 D8 D7 2C 1D  ...........D..,.
0010: AF 21 95 B7 1D A4 54 E5   11 74 1B                 .!....T..t.
main, called closeSocket(selfInitiated)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
Server ended
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a compatibility thing for broken implementations. Your sessions is established using `SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA`, so there is really no problem. I don't think you can control it via the `setEnabledCipherSuites()`, it's most probably an integral part of the TLS implementation.

Comment: I was just afraid that I suddenly would not have encryption since my client send two cipher to choose from I understand that one of them is of course no cipher, but anyway

Comment: As the RFC says: 'This SCSV is not a true cipher suite (it does not correspond to any valid set of algorithms) and cannot be negotiated'. So there is no way for it to be used for the session. You only have one other, so that is selected.